# How to clean HTML tags after scraping using BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Building a super basic script in Python to get some pricing data from Etsy. I know the code is ugly (any better practice tips are greatly appreciated), but it is doing exactly what I need.

My only question is: is there an easy, clean way to only grab **$305.00+** without the HTML tags associated? Maybe I need some regex - but I feel there needs to be a cleaner way, or a better package to use or something.. I've also seen before 'find_element_by_class' but I think that's using Selenium and it's a lot slower.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

weblink = 'https://www.etsy.com/listing/567269694/saw-blade-gyuto-japanese-style-chef?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=chef%20knife&ref=sr_gallery-1-17'

def grabData(url):
    res = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")

    price = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'listing-price'})
    print(price)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grabData(weblink)
```

The output:

```
<span class="vertical-align-middle " id="listing-price">
                        $305.00+

                <meta content="USD" itemprop="currency"/>
<meta content="305.00" itemprop="price"/>
<meta content="in_stock" itemprop="availability"/>
</span>
```

---

Nevermind, I've solved it. All you have to do is add `.text` to the end.

Comment: No, It hasn't been solved yet. All you need to do is add `.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.text` to get only the desired item kicking out extra whitespaces around.

Comment: @SIM yeah I added `.strip()` also, but I like your style more. Thanks!